# CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile returns Success and then recurring profile gets cancelled instantly, Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Paypal recurring API. In sandbox mode when i create a recurring profile using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile, it returns success as response
The request and response for CreateRecurringPaymentProfile are:

Request:

```
`&TOKEN=EC-6VH029039A9xxxxxx&PAYERID=&PROFILESTARTDATE=2013-08-29T18%3A44%3A52Z&DESC=Premium+Membership&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=xx&INITAMT=x.xx&FAILEDINITAMTACTION=CancelOnFailure&AMT=9.99&CURRENCYCODE=USD&COUNTRYCODE=US&MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3&AUTOBILLOUTAMT=AddToNextBilling`
```

Response:

```
`array(7) (
  [PROFILEID] => (string) I%xxxxxxUMYEMFxx
  [PROFILESTATUS] => (string) PendingProfile
  [TIMESTAMP] => (string) 2013%2d07%2d30T18%3a45%3a16Z
  [CORRELATIONID] => (string) 424d12027ab90
  [ACK] => (string) Success
  [VERSION] => (string) 86%2e0
  [BUILD] => (string) 7084400
)`
```

Also it shows Pending profile on sandbox account. For some cases it activates the profile and charges the initial amount and for some cases the profile gets cancelled by itself. This happened to me before when negative testing was on, but now it happens even if negative testing is off. Again it happens in some cases not all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You're using INITAMT and FAILEDINITAMTACTION=CancelOnFailure, so it sounds like you're getting exactly what should be expected.

If for some reason the initial amount cannot be charged it will immediately suspend the profile.

Comment: So now i have set FAILEDINITAMTACTION=ContinueOnFailure and for all the profile creation the status is pending and the initial amount doesn't go through.

Comment: What funding sources does your payer account have configured?